# Why does MATLAB complain it  "forbids the use of the same name ... as both a function and a variable"?

Tags: user-interface, uitableview, matlab, matlab-guide

Hye guys. Okay. I have done this coding. But it seems have error. Can anyone explain to me why there is an error? This is the coding:

```
Hcurve = cell2mat(get(handles.Mytable3,'Data'));
costA = cell2mat(get(handles.Mytable1,'Data'));
cost1 = str2num(get(handles.input2_editText,'String'));
cost2 = str2num(get(handles.input3_editText,'String'));
cost3 = str2num(get(handles.input4_editText,'String'));
cost4 = str2num(get(handles.input5_editText,'String'));
limit = cell2mat(get(handles.Mytable2,'Data'));
Pdt = str2num(get(handles.input1_editText,'String'));

if isempty(costA)

    if size(Hcurve,1) == 2

        H1 = Hcurve(1,:)*cost1;
        H2 = Hcurve(2,:)*cost2;
        H = num2cell([H1;H2]);
        set(handles.Mytable1,'Data',H)
        cost = cell2mat(get(handles.Mytable1,'Data'));

    else if size(Hcurve,1) == 3 

        H1 = Hcurve(1,:)*cost1;
        H2 = Hcurve(2,:)*cost2;
        H3 = Hcurve(3,:)*cost3;
        H = num2cell([H1;H2;H3]);
        set(handles.Mytable1,'Data',H)
        cost = cell2mat(get(handles.Mytable1,'Data'));

    else if size(Hcurve,1) == 4 

        H1 = Hcurve(1,:)*cost1;
        H2 = Hcurve(2,:)*cost2;
        H3 = Hcurve(3,:)*cost3;
        H4 = Hcurve(3,:)*cost4;
        H = num2cell([H1;H2;H3;H4]);
        set(handles.Mytable1,'Data',H)
        cost = cell2mat(get(handles.Mytable1,'Data'));

        else 

        cost = costA;

        end
        end
    end
end


if size(cost,1) == 1

    set(handles.text8,'String','At Lease Two Generators');
```

This is the error occured:

??? At compilation, "cost" was determined to be a variable and this
 variable is uninitialized.  "cost" is also a function name and previous versions
 of MATLAB would have called the function.
 However, MATLAB 7 forbids the use of the same name in the same
 context as both a function and a variable.

Error in ==> fyp_editor>Mybutton_Callback at 131
    if size(cost,1) == 1

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> fyp_editor at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)fyp_editor('Mybutton_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likely problem you're having is that `costA` is not empty, so *none* of your nested code gets evaluated and the variable `cost` will never be initialized to anything before you call the line `if size(cost,1) == 1`. You probably want to order your [nested if statements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/if.html) something like this:

```
if isempty(costA)  %# If costA is empty, compute a value for cost

  if size(Hcurve,1) == 2
  ...
  elseif size(Hcurve,1) == 3
  ...
  elseif size(Hcurve,1) == 4
  ...
  end

else
  cost = costA;  %# Will set cost equal to costA if it is not empty
end
```

The explanation for the unusual error you're getting is that `cost` appears in your code as a *variable*, but there appears to be a *function* with the name `cost` as well. When you define a variable with the same name as a function, the [variable takes precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-58170.html#bresuvu-6) and will be used instead of the function whenever that name is used in any computations.

Even though `cost` doesn't get initialized to anything in your condition, MATLAB still recognizes that it *could* be a variable in your function and thus (in MATLAB 7 or newer) it doesn't try to call the *function* `cost`. Apparently, in older versions MATLAB would call the shadowed function in the event that a variable by the same name is uninitialized.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the error is saying that the `cost` variable is a reserved word. This means you can't use this name as a variable.

Try renaming `cost` to something else, like `finalCost`.

Comment: `cost` is not a MATLAB [keyword](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/iskeyword.html). There *is* a built-in function [cost](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/dsp/ref/cost.html) but that wouldn't be a problem, since MATLAB realizes he wants to use it as a  variable, except he uses it when it is not initialized.